# How to stop/prevent redirection when uploading image in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

I have implemented code to upload image in angular but i am stuck as image is uploading but form get redirect to the url specified in the location below is my code please help.

```
<form #form action="http://localhost:8084/api/admin/product/images" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" required multiple />
<input type="submit" (click)="form.submit()"  class="btn btn-primary" 
value="Upload" />  
</form>
```

I want to upload image but user should stay on the same page not to redirect i also have implemented some solution but none of them work in my case please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Better Solution:**

In angular, we usually do it in more smarter way.
in component.html:

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" (click)="onImageChanged($event)"/>
<input type="submit" (click)="submit()"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" /> 
</form>
```

and in component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  name = 'Angular';
  selectedImage: File;
  onImageChanged(event) {
    const temp = event.target.files[0];
    this.selectedImage = temp;
  }
  submit(event) {
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('image', this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name);
    this.http.post(`"http://localhost:8084/api/admin/product/images`, uploadData).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Then you will not face such redirect problem.

**Workaround Solution:**

you can use a iframe with no width and height and target the form to this iframe.

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0" name="dummyframe" id="dummyframe"></iframe>
<form #form action="http://localhost:8084/api/admin/product/images" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" target="dummyframe">
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" required multiple />
<input type="submit" (click)="form.submit();submit($event)"  class="btn btn-primary" 
value="Upload" />  
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You Md. Rafee for your kind help.